# Filter data frame based on absolute difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm, sorting

I have the following data frame:

```py
import pandas as pd
d1 = {'id': ["car", "car", "car", "plane", "plane", "car"], 'value': [1, 1.2, 5, 6, 1.3, 0.8]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)
df1
```

```py
    id      value
0   car     1.0
1   car     1.2
2   car     5.0
3   plane   6.0
4   plane   1.3
5   car     0.8
```

I want to filter rows out, if all differences for a value are smaller than 1, so I get the following data frames:

```py
d2 = {'id': ["car", "car", "car"], 'value': [1, 1.2, 0.8]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
df2
```

```py
    id      value
0   car     1.0
1   car     1.2
5   car     0.8
```

and

```py
d3 = {'id': ["car", "plane", "plane"], 'value': [5, 6, 1.3]}
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data=d3)
df3
```

```py
2   car     5.0
3   plane   6.0
4   plane   1.3
```

I tried the following function to save all values in a temporary list, but it did not work properly:

```py
unique_list = []
def unique_2(df):
    for id_1, value_1 in zip(df["id"], df["value"]):
        for id_2, value_2 in zip(df["id"], df["value"]):
            if id_1 == id_2:
                if abs(value_1-value_2) > 0.01: 
                    x = True
                    unique_list.append(x)
                else:
                    x = False
                    unique_list.append(x)
            else:
                pass
```

Comment: In your second output 6 and 16 are more than 1 apart

Comment: "if all differences for a value are smaller than 1". With this assertion, it's not possible to split "car" in 2 lists because you can't have ALL differences smaller than 1. "1-5", "1.2-5", "0.8-5". What is the logic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a custom [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) to split the data:

```
grp = df1['value'].sort_values().diff().gt(1).cumsum()

out = [g for _, g in df1.groupby(grp)]
```

*Note that it wasn't clear whether you want to use `<1` or `≤1` as threshold. If you want `<1` replace `gt(1)` by `ge(1)`.*

Output:

```
[    id  value
 0  car    1.0
 1  car    1.2
 5  car    0.8,
       id  value
 2    car    5.0
 3  plane    6.0,
       id  value
 4  plane   16.0]
```

Intermediate `grp`:

```
5    0
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

##### grouping loners together

Assuming a different interpretation, if you want to groups loners (=rows that have no other row within 1) together, use:

```
grp = df1['value'].sort_values().diff().ge(1).cumsum()
grp = grp.mask(df1.groupby(grp).transform('size').eq(1), 'alone')

out = [g for _, g in df1.groupby(grp)]
```

*Note that we're only grouping rows that are less than 1 apart*

Output:

```
[    id  value
 0  car    1.0
 1  car    1.2
 5  car    0.8,
       id  value
 2    car    5.0
 3  plane    6.0
 4  plane   16.0]
```

Intermediate `grp`:

```
5        0
0        0
1        0
2    alone
3    alone
4    alone
Name: value, dtype: object
```

###### by ID:

```
grp = df1.sort_values(by='value').groupby('id', group_keys=False)['value'].apply(lambda g: g.diff().gt(1).cumsum())
grp = grp.mask(df1.groupby(['id', grp]).transform('size').eq(1), 'alone')

out = [g for _, g in df1.groupby(grp)]
```

Output:

```
[    id  value
 0  car    1.0
 1  car    1.2
 5  car    0.8,
       id  value
 2    car    5.0
 3  plane    6.0
 4  plane    1.3]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Is it possible to do the grouping operation only an values with the same id? If I add in another row with id=plane and value=1.3, it should get sorted in the second df.

Comment: Yes, add this ID in the groupby! `df1['value'].sort_values().apply(lambda g: g.diff().gt(1).cumsum())`

Comment: Thanks, I am unsure where to add the "id" in the groupby, can you be more specific?

Comment: So to be clear, you want one dataframe per group for those that have values within 1, and one dataframe for all the rest?

Comment: Yes, one dataframe per id-group for those values within 1, and one dataframe for the rest. I edited the data frames in the original post to be more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Het differencies with column `value` with numpy broadcasting, get absolute values, comapre less like `1` with set `False` to diagonal:

```
a = df1['value'].to_numpy()

m = np.abs(a - a[:, None]) < 1
np.fill_diagonal(m, False)
print (m)

[[False  True False False False  True]
 [ True False False False False  True]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [False False False False False False]
 [ True  True False False False False]]
```

Last fitler rows with at least one `True` per rows:

```
mask = np.any(m, axis=1)
df11, df22 = df1[mask], df1[~mask]
print (df11)
    id  value
0  car    1.0
1  car    1.2
5  car    0.8

print (df22)
      id  value
2    car    5.0
3  plane    6.0
4  plane   16.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no solution because the logic is unclear:

> I want to filter rows out, if all differences for a value are smaller than 1

```
def debug(sr):
   print(f'[{sr.name}]')
   arr = sr.values
   val = np.abs(sr.values - sr.values[:, None])
   print(pd.DataFrame(val, sr.tolist(), sr.tolist()))
   print()
   return np.max(val)

df1.groupby('id')['value'].transform(debug)
```

Output:

```
[car]
     1.0  1.2  5.0  0.8
1.0  0.0  0.2  4.0  0.2  # one difference > 1
1.2  0.2  0.0  3.8  0.4  # one difference > 1
5.0  4.0  3.8  0.0  4.2  # 3 differences > 1
0.8  0.2  0.4  4.2  0.0  # 1 difference > 1

[plane]
      6.0   16.0
6.0    0.0  10.0
16.0  10.0   0.0

0     4.2  # car group difference > 1
1     4.2
2     4.2
3    10.0  # plane group difference > 1
4    10.0
5     4.2
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

As you can see, for each combination, there is at least one value whose difference is greater than 1. So for a given group, you can't split it into two parts. You can only set the whole group to one of the two lists:

- group1: all absolute differences is lower or equals than 1
- group2: at least one difference is greater than 1